# Automate Animation according to time

Tags: android, animation, automation, system, lottie

I was working on an app and thought to create some animation in the splash screen of the app same as **Google Doodle**. 
Animations would be according to time, I have sets of FestivalName , start and end date of the festivals like Christmas, new year etc. Start and end date will trigger the animation automatically.

I tried Airbnb's Lottie to do so. But storing all the animations files in assests is increasing the apk size by almost 5-6 mb. I tried to Optimize this by just storing 1 animation file and changing the file by a script. So whenever I need to change the animation , I run the below from root folder and the animations are changed.

Here is the script :

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf app/src/main/assets/animation.json
curl "$1" > app/src/main/assets/animation.json
```

It takes the parameter as a link which have the animation and download the file in assets file.

[Animation Link](https://api.myjson.com/bins/uqc1s)

This approach increases only 716kb. But This doesn't seems to be automated, I want to know any other best approach for this which should be automated.

Comment: It would help to know what you mean saying "This doesn't seems to be automated". What is the best result for you? You must trigger the update when you want it to run and I'm sure you don't want to annoy the users with a lot of unexpected traffic.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the file name method, it will automatically put the serialization task and composition in a cache. So, you can just call that function with no listeners when you want to start getting it ready for the cache then call it again when you actually need it.